# Update multiple Application IDs

Tags: install4j

I have a case where our build server managed to lose an application id for our product and create a new one in its place. I'd like to be able to issue a new installer that can update both the rogue application id as well as the valid application id. Is this possible to do very early in the process? I've managed to tie into the directory location user input validation script, but that seems to be introducing vagaries in the directory selection process. Our overall goal is to handle everything silently and get all installations back on the proper track.

Optimally, I'd like to be able to just give a list of valid application ids to the install4j project and let it handle things itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to adjust the installation directory in a "Run script" action in the startup node of your installer:

```
ApplicationRegistry.ApplicationInfo[] applicationInfos =
    ApplicationRegistry.getApplicationInfoById("the wrong ID");

if (applicationInfos.length > 0) {
    File oldDir = applicationInfos[0].getInstallationDirectory(); 
    context.setInstallationDirectory(oldDir);
}
return true;
```

On the "Installation location" screen, the "Validate application id" property has to be deselected.

Comment: Thank you for this. I did end up extending it to only run my checks if the installer thinks the app wasn't installed before.